# Asymetric behaviour in user command with conditionals

Tags: macros, conditionals

I use frequently a user defined command to highlight modifications in latex documents.

```
\providecommand{\ifeqthenelse}[4]{\edef\tempa{#1}\def\tempb{#2}\ifx\tempa\tempb {#3} \else {#4}\fi}

\providecommand{\changed}[5]{{\ifeqthenelse{#3}{#5}{{\color{black}#1}}{\color{#4}#1}}%
{\ifeqthenelse{#3}{#5}{}{\color{grey}\ifeqthenelse{#2}{}{}{(}#2\ifeqthenelse{#2}{}{}{)~}}}%
{\ifeqthenelse{#3}{#5}{}{\ifeqthenelse{#3}{}{}{[}{\it\color{#4}#3}\ifeqthenelse{#3}{}{}{]~}}}}

\providecommand{\mychanged}[3]{\changed{#1}{#2}{#3}{blue}{accept}}
```

The last command mychanged is actually used when making modifications. Its first argument will be the new text and its second argument the old text. Finally the third argument is used by others to accept my modifications by providing accept. Now I find that the behaviour of mychanged is asymmetric in the first two arguments in the following sense: I can use all kinds of complex latex like equations, citations and references in the first argument, while in the second argument citations and references often lead to latex errors. For this reason I always need to modify the old text. This second argument enters the conditionals of the ifeqthenelse command so I suspect that this is why it does not work. Is there a suitable replacement for ifeqthenelse e.g. a better way to construct a if-then-else conditional which will accept even citations etc. in a string comparison? Note that, preferably, I would like to avoid using packages escpecially if they are not platform/distribution independent.

Here is a full example. It works but stops working if you uncomment the second line in the document enviroment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}

\providecommand{\ifeqthenelse}[4]{\edef\tempa{#1}\def\tempb{#2}\ifx\tempa\tempb {#3} \else {#4}\fi}

\providecommand{\changed}[5]{{\ifeqthenelse{#3}{#5}{{\color{black}#1}}{\color{#4}#1}}%
{\ifeqthenelse{#3}{#5}{}{\color{grey}\ifeqthenelse{#2}{}{}{(}#2\ifeqthenelse{#2}{}{}{)~}}}%
{\ifeqthenelse{#3}{#5}{}{\ifeqthenelse{#3}{}{}{[}{\it\color{#4}#3}\ifeqthenelse{#3}{}{}{]~}}}}

\providecommand{\mychanged}[3]{\changed{#1}{#2}{#3}{blue}{accept}}

\begin{document}

\section{test}

This is a \mychanged{cite \cite{Fukugita:1986hr}}{}{}.
%This is a \mychanged{}{cite \cite{Fukugita:1986hr}}{}.

\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname bibnamefont\endcsname\relax
  \def\bibnamefont#1{#1}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname bibfnamefont\endcsname\relax
  \def\bibfnamefont#1{#1}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname citenamefont\endcsname\relax
  \def\citenamefont#1{#1}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
  \def\url#1{\texttt{#1}}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
\providecommand{\eprint}[2][]{\url{#2}}

\bibitem[{\citenamefont{Fukugita and Yanagida}(1986)}]{Fukugita:1986hr}
\bibinfo{author}{\bibfnamefont{M.}~\bibnamefont{Fukugita}} \bibnamefont{and}
  \bibinfo{author}{\bibfnamefont{T.}~\bibnamefont{Yanagida}},
  \bibinfo{journal}{Phys. Lett. B} \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{174}},
  \bibinfo{pages}{45} (\bibinfo{year}{1986}).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

---

Ilustration for swallowed spaces in current version (there is no space between "a" and "test" but it would be very nice if there was one)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}

\newcommand{\printifnonempty}[2]{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else#2\fi}
\newcommand{\changed}[5]{%
  \def\temp{#3}%
  \def\accept{#5}%
  \ifx\temp\accept
    #1
  \else
    \textcolor{#4}{\printifnonempty{#1}{#1}}%
    \textcolor{grey}{\printifnonempty{#2}{(#2)}}%
    \textcolor{#4}{\printifnonempty{#3}{[#3]}}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

This is a\changed{ test}{ old}{comment}{blue}{accept}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note, that in the critical cases I always compare with an empty string, so the ifeqthenelse command might be reduced to something simpler in these cases.

Comment: The definition *is* asymmetric: there's `\edef` for `\tempa` and `\def` for `\tempb`. A real "use case" should be good for suggesting some improvement.

Comment: Yes, but as I stated also the mychanged command uses only the second argument (not the first) in calls of ifeqthenelse. I included a full example in the question

Comment: I get no error if I uncomment the second example, after having changed `\edef` into `\def`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the `\edef` that starts the definition of `\ifeqthenelse`. Change it into `\def`.

However there's a neater way to do it:

```
\def\accept{accept}
\newcommand{\mychanged}[3]{%
  \def\temp{#3}%
  \ifx\temp\accept
    #1
  \else
    \textcolor{blue}{\printifnonempty{#1}{#1}}%
    \textcolor{grey}{\printifnonempty{#2}{(#2)}}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\printifnonempty}[2]{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else#2\fi}
```

Comment: This is not completely equivalent to the above (wrt. argument #3) but it can be modified in an obvious way. In this context: why is the \def\temp{#3} needed?

Comment: @user429540 It's for the following test: we check if `#3` is equal to `accept`.

Comment: Ah I overlooked this because my actual case is slightly different (which was why I needed the \edef). Except for the small difference it is even better than my old solution because it does not add spurious extra white space.

Comment: @user429540 Using `\edef` is quite dangerous: for example `\cite` doesn't survive it, but also `\textbf` and many other commands.

Comment: Maybe one more comment. The above swallows leading spaces in the first argument. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user429540 May you show an example?

Comment: See the extended question.

Comment: @user429540 It doesn't swallow spaces:  when argument `#1` is ignored the space is not inserted, of course.

Comment: But the argument #1 is not ignored. My output is "This is atest ( old)[c omment] .", so argument #1 "test" is shown.

Comment: @user429540 It is `\textcolor` that eats the space. Write `\changed{{ test}}...` if you want to preserve the space.

Comment: I found that additional curly brackets in the \printifnonempty{} command will fix this as well.

Comment: One further issue which I found only now is that empty (or just whitespace lines in the arguments) will produce a latex error `Paragraph endet before \@textcolor was complete`. Any ideas?

Comment: @highsciguy Use `\long\def\temp{#3}` and `\long\def\accept{accept}`